# NSData dataWithContentOfFile returning nil?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdata

I have a file path, and I need to get the data of the file in NSData. I am using:

```
NSError *err = nil;
NSData *d = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:file options:nil error:&err];

NSLog(@"error: %@", err);
```

Error is:

```
 Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)" UserInfo=0x34a8f0 {NSFilePath=file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/A19223D4-0AEF-4677-8EDD-0D2CA9A7BB73/Documents/12-03-25%2022:10:48--cc.mp4, NSUnderlyingError=0x34a560 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}
```

But the file/directory does exist because I am playing the video file and it works just fine:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *controller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[video filepath]]];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:controller];
```

What is going wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are passing a URL in string format to dataWithContentsOfFile, you have to use the "file path" for the file.

In this case you have to remove "file://localhost" from the string. If the file exists, that should work.

Comment: Is there a convenient method on NSString that will let me remove file://localhost

Comment: Do not simply remove the "file://localhost" prefix. Use `NSString *path = [[NSURL URLWithString:file] path];` to convert the file URL to a unix path.

Comment: YES, in NSURL class you have [url path]. But you have the url as string, so you have to create the url first like: NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:yourURLString]

Comment: @LuisEspinoza That's what I wrote, or am I missing something?

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe YES...are the same thing...my web view was not refreshed with your comment when i wrote it. ;)

Comment: Ah, sorry for sounding a little disgruntled :)